# Change Simulation Nodes bake directory

Tags: cache, simulation-nodes

How can I manually specify the location where the *Simulation Nodes* data is baked?

Answer (score 5):

Just found it.

It's under the **Internal Dependencies** option in the modifier:

[image]

Comment: --Does it actually bake for you?  My baking directory remains empty, and there is no option anywhere to bake.--  Never mind; finally found it under the `Physics` properties.